# How to avoid cell duplicate values in tableview/collectionview in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to avoid **tableview/collectionview** cells with duplicate values.

Here is my code :

```
 NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[finalImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
 NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Comment: Please post existing code. Anyhow, you can moderate it from Data source.

Comment: Add your code, your question doesn't have much description about your problem.

Comment: Actually , when i scroll the collectionview the same images repeated more than one times

Comment: try `imageView.image=nil;` before fetching image, by the way your should use cache to fetch images like this, as the you are not getting images immediately and your imageView keeps the old image due to dequeue of cell.

Comment: The cellforindex calls everytime when we scroll the collectionview that time the values will be repeated in more than times

Comment: Add you **cellForRowAtIndexPath**'s code

Comment: imageView.image=nil; I used this method , i am still facing the same problem

Comment: yes , i used the cellForRowAtIndexPath's, thats why i faced the problem because cellForRowAtIndexPath's executes repeatedly

Comment: Data repeat in UITableView when scrolling

Comment: Don't add code in the comments, **edit** your question.

Comment: The problem is `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];` this is synchronous call, you should use asynchronous call to fetch images, use library like [SDWebCache](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Comment: Even i faced the problem in NSArray values to assign the tableview cell , the values is repeated when i scrolling the tableview

Answer (score 0):

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *imagesArray; //Array of URL for images
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *dataDictionary; // Using to store downloaded data
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
//Some images for test        
self.imagesArray = @[@"https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/05/31/18/38/sea-2361247__480.jpg", @"https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/06/02/11/49/still-life-2366084__480.jpg", @"https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/06/04/20/31/sheep-2372148__480.jpg", @"https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/06/04/15/08/architecture-2371294__480.jpg", @"https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/05/18/21/54/tower-bridge-2324875__480.jpg", @"https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/05/16/21/24/gorilla-2318998__480.jpg", @"https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/05/24/11/40/desert-2340326__480.jpg", @"https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/05/21/15/14/balloon-2331488__480.jpg", @"https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/05/19/15/16/countryside-2326787__480.jpg", @"https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/04/09/09/56/avenue-2215317__480.jpg"];

    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;


    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    self.dataDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];
}

- (void)asyncImageForIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath onCompletion: (void(^)(UIImage *image))completionBlock {

    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    if ([self.dataDictionary objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)indexPath.row]]) {
            completionBlock([UIImage imageWithData:[self.dataDictionary objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)indexPath.row]]]);
    }

//Sending async request not to block main thread and storing it into the dictionary
//After storing, reloading table view on main thread. So the function is called again, but as we have stored NSData for image, method won't send request
        [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:imageURL completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if(!error) {
                [self.dataDictionary setObject:data forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", indexPath.row]];
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self.tableView reloadData];
                });

        }
    }] resume];

}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 250;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.imagesArray.count;
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    //Downloading image separated into another method
    [self asyncImageForIndexPath:indexPath onCompletion:^(UIImage *image) {
        cell.imageView.image = image;
    }];


    return cell;
}
```

Try out the code, and let me know if that helps. If you have any questions, feel free to ask